# Need to change UTC date-time in this format 2017-03-30 21:25:09 to other time zone. Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

I have the following string in UTC format: `"2017-03-30 21:25:09"`. I need to convert this to the `"America/Los_Angeles" and "America/New_York"` time zone.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
utc_time = Time.parse(to_datetime.to_s).utc
pacific_time = utc_time + Time.zone_offset("PDT")
```

I also tried using [DateTime#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), but that didn't work either.

```
to_datetime = DateTime.strptime(my_time_string, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

How can I change the string so that it refers to the different time zone?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you. "I am having hard time doing this" doesn't tell us anything useful.

Comment: I spent a lot of time doing research. 
utc_time = Time.parse(to_datetime.to_s).utc
pacific_time = utc_time + Time.zone_offset("PDT") 

It didn't work for me. Also, I tried changing that string to date format and tried converting: 
to_datetime = DateTime.strptime(my_time_string, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Finally, i just couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Don't add the information in a comment, modify your question and incorporate that information into it. The more you tell us about what you tried, the faster we can isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TZInfo gem](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo).

```
require 'tzinfo'

# parse the UTC time
utcTime = Time.parse("2017-03-30 21:25:09 UTC")
puts utcTime # "2017-03-30 21:25:09 UTC"

# convert it to a time zone
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
localTime = tz.utc_to_local(utcTime)
# you cannot just puts this localTime, because the abbrevation will be incorrect

# you can get format directly from here and get the correct abbreviation with %Z
localString = tz.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", utc = utcTime)
puts localString # "2017-03-30 17:25:09 EDT"

# as of v1.2.3, you can get the offset correctly with %z
localString = tz.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z", utc = utcTime)
puts localString # "2017-03-30 17:25:09 -04:00"

# for older versions of tzinfo, %z didn't work so you had to create the offset manually
offset = tz.period_for_utc(utcTime).utc_total_offset
hoursOffset = (offset / 3600.0).truncate
minutesOffset = (offset.abs / 60) % 60
offsetString = sprintf("%+03d:%02d", hoursOffset, minutesOffset)
puts offsetString # "-04:00"
```

Comment: It looks promising to me, is there any way to put the offset value on the value of local?

Comment: Updated to show this.  Be sure to check out the full TZInfo gem docs.

Comment: You are awesome. That was exactly what i was looking for. Just for my knowledge is there any way to do the opposite? other time zone to UTC? I might need to know this in future?

Comment: FYI - Version 1.2.3 of the TZInfo gem fixed the `%z` problem.  See [this issue](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/issues/67).

Answer (score 1):

ActiveSupport provides the `in_time_zone` helper method. For example, you can set the TimeZone manually, instead of using the operating system's time zone.

```
Time.zone = 'Hawaii'             # => 'Hawaii'
DateTime.new(2000).in_time_zone  # => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 14:00:00 HST -10:00
```

You can also pass in a TimeZone instance or string that identifies a TimeZone as an argument, and the conversion will be based on that zone instead of `Time.zone`.

```
DateTime.new(2000).in_time_zone('Alaska') # => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 15:00:00 AKST -09:00
```

More info is in "[ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html)".

Comment: Not all Ruby is Rails.  Also, Rails time zone names are non-standard.

Comment: I understand that. I guess whats the difference between loading the TZInfo gem or requiring the ActiveSupport::TimeWIthZone class in any other ruby class? Also, you can use the standard names as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson .

```
Input =>  convert_date_from_utc('2017-03-20 22:29:26', 'America/New_York')
Output=>  2017-03-20T18:29:26-04:00

  # convert utc date to other time_zone with offset
  def convert_date_from_utc(date, time_zone)
    utcTime = Time.parse(date)
    tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get(time_zone)
    local_time = tz.utc_to_local(utcTime).to_s[0..18].gsub!(' ','T')
    offset = tz.period_for_utc(utcTime).utc_total_offset
    hoursOffset = (offset / 3600.0).truncate
    minutesOffset = (offset.abs / 60) % 60
    offsetString = sprintf("%+03d:%02d", hoursOffset, minutesOffset)
    local_time+offsetString
  end
```